# Утилита для работы с PostgreSQL

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Всем привет. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, адекватную утилиту для работы с PostgreSQL, а то стандартный pgAdmin что-то не радует вовсе.

Нужен удобный редактор запросов с функцией IntelliSense. Средства для администрирования БД (резервное копирование, возможность остановить, запустить сервер и т.д.). Просмотр схемы БД в виде диаграмм. ОС - Windows.

Comment: Вам с графическим интерфейсом?

Comment: В идеале хотелось что-то наподобие Sql Management Studio.

Comment: IBexpert. Изначально для Interbase и Firebird. Со временем обросла поддержкой других БД. Postgres упоминается на сайте. Может поддерживает. кто знает. Для жителей бывшего СССР была бесплатной. Как сейчас не знаю.

Comment: на вкус и цвет утилиты разные. чем вас не устроила стандартная админка? чего именно хочется от альтернативы?

Comment: И на какой ОС собираетесь использовать?

Comment: Разве бывают ОС кроме Windows?

Comment: psql же :). Серьезно, 0xDBE от JetBrains хороша, но платная. Если же не приходится копипастить большие объёмы результатов запросов, то не понимаю, чем pgAdmin не устроил. У меня это единственная причина отказа от использования pgAdmin. Причем, старые версии не страдали данным недостатком. Сам пользуясь собственным продуктом + pgAdmin для еще не реализованных фишек.

Comment: Нужен удобный редактор запросов с функцией IntelliSense. Средства для администрирования БД (резервное копирование, возможность остановить, запустить сервер и т.д.).Просмотр схемы БД в виде диаграмм. ОС - Windows

Comment: @Vitalts она в данный момент не платная, она еще в preview. Я даже как платник сейчас не могу зайти в просроченный билд.

Comment: @Etki, все ещё? Вот это они затянули с релизом... Тем более, надо пробовать, хороший продукт.

Answer (score 3):

EMS SQL Manager for PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй heidisql там поддержка Postgres появилась

Answer (score 0):

https://www.jetbrains.com/dbe/ 
Есть такая среда для работы с БД. Но лично мне больше нравится pgAdmin.